# Depurar eventos associados via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quando desejo depurar um evento associado a um elemento via jQuery, atualmente, consigo fazer das seguintes formas:

- no Chrome, é possível ativar o depurador especificamente para certos tipos de eventos. No entanto, isso não tem utilidade quando se é necessário depurar alguma coisa em outros navegadores;
- colocar uma instrução `debugger` na primeira linha de código de um evento ativa o depurador naquele ponto, mas é inconveniente fazê-lo para cada evento. Além disso, para casos nos quais vou depurar código alheio, ainda há o trabalho de se obter todos os eventos - que podem ser associados e desassociados (amarrados/desamarrados?) dinamicamente.
- Força bruta. Por exemplo, para um evento de clique:

  ```
  function debugClick (elem) {
      debugger;
      $(elem).click();
  }
  ```

Esse último exemplo faz com que eu me sinta mal comigo mesmo.

Existe alguma forma mais elegante e *cross browser* de se depurar os eventos de um elemento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ferramentas de desenvolvimento do Chrome são uma excelente ajuda para encontrar os *event handlers* .

Infelizmente, quando se trata de jQuery, o *event handler* que é exibido é o do jQuery e não aquele que registamos (o jQuery adiciona alguma funcionalidade e é por isso que vemos o handler do jquery em vez do nosso).

Podemos aceder ao nosso handler da seguinte forma:

```
$._data($("#idDoElemento").get(0), "events")
```

Como alternativa existe um pequeno script (disclaimer: sou o dono desse projecto) que permite usar um selector jQuery para encontrar os eventos em que estamos interessados, por examplo, escrevendo na consola do chrome depois de importar [findHandlersJS](https://github.com/ruidfigueiredo/findHandlersJS)

```
findEventHandlers("click", "*")
```

Retorna todos os *event handlers* para clicks em qualquer tipo de elemento na pagina que estamos.

Outro exemplo:

```
findEventHandlers("click", "div#items :button")
```

retorna todos os event handlers para clique nos botões dentro do div com id="items"

Mais informação sobre findHandlersJS [**aqui**(esta em inglês)](http://blinkingcaret.wordpress.com/2014/01/17/quickly-finding-and-debugging-jquery-event-handlers/).

E [**aqui**](http://findhandlersjsexample.azurewebsites.net/) podem encontrar um site exemplo com o findHandlersJS instalado e pronto para usar na consola do chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode debuggar ou pausar eventos de clique com a aba *Event Listeners* do ChromeDev Tools:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Clique aqui para ver a imagem em tamanho maior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcOsM.png)

Comment: Eu gosto dessa resposta, mas é exatamente o que eu mencionei como a primeira das minhas alternativas (`"no Chrome, é possível ativar o depurador especificamente para certos tipos de eventos"`). Mesmo assim, +1 por elaborar sobre como fazer isso, pra servir de referência para quem ler a pergunta.